# can we provide 2 actions with "Run keyword if" built in function for robot framework

Tags: robotframework

```
    Run Keyword If    '${var1}'=='@{var2}[1]'    Run Keyword And Return Status    Check for Help Tab  Click on Help button
```

This is the example code, i have to perform. i have to perform two actions for this using robot framework with RIDE platform, but it is showing me error like expected 0 arguments, got 1. i understand the error, but what if i have to perform 2 actions here itself or i have to put another keyword 'Click on help button' in the first keyword to 'Check for help tab'.

Answer (score 4):

### Using 'Run Keywords'

You can run the keyword [run keywords](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keywords), at which point you can run multiple keywords.

Example:

```
*** Test cases ***
Example
    run keyword if  1 == 1  run keywords
    ...  log  this is a normal log
    ...  AND  log  this is a warning  WARN
    ...  AND  log to console  this is a log to the console
```

### Using a custom keyword

Your other option is to create a custom keyword that does everything you need it to do, and call that keyword:

Example:

```
*** Keywords ***
Do some logging
    log  this is a normal log
    log  this is a warning  WARN
    log to console  this is a log to the console

*** Test cases ***
Example
    run keyword if  1 == 1  Do some logging
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan for this suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The error says that Check for Help Tab needs no arguments, but one was given. The given argument was the second keyword: Click on Help Button.

I know two ways you can do this, i recommend the first:

1) Define a new keyword:

```
Check Help Tab and Click Help Button
    Check for Help Tab
    Click on Help Button
```

and use it like this:

```
Run Keyword If    '${var1}'=='@{var2}[1]'    Run Keyword And Return Status    Check Help Tab and Click Help button
```

or 
2)

```
Run Keyword If    '${var1}'=='@{var2}[1]'    Run Keyword And Return Status    Check Help Tab 
Run Keyword If    '${var1}'=='@{var2}[1]'    Run Keyword And Return Status    Click Help button
```

Comment: Thanks for this reply. I will implement in the same way

Comment: As highlighted by Bryan, this is possible using a standard keyword.